# CGContextAddArc draw multiple circle at different sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have these sizes that I want to draw a circle with (both width and height are the same obviously)

```
205.0
218.0
245.0
257.0
310.0
510.0
```

When I draw my circle at 205.5 its fine, its a perfect circle. But when I start with 218, the circle gets cut off a little and it gets more and more cut off each time I try to make a bigger circle. My question is, how do I create a circle that is perfect, no matter what the size ?

Here is my code:

```
func drawCircle()
{
    // Get the Graphics Context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the circle outerline-width
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

    // Set the circle outerline-colour
    UIColor.redColor().set()

    // Create Circle
    CGContextAddArc(context, (round(frame.size.width))/2, round(frame.size.height)/2, (round(frame.size.width) - 10)/2, 0.0, CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), 1)

    // Draw
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

`frame.size.width` and `frame.size.height` are the numbers of 205, 218 and so on. I will accept an Objective-C answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "cut off"?  It's not drawing all the way around the circle? Or could it be that it extends past the edge of it's container view or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw a circle, [use `CGContext.addEllipse(in:)` a.k.a. `CGContextAddEllipseInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456420-addellipse) instead of `CGContextAddArc`.

```
// swift 3:
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
context.setLineWidth(5.0)
UIColor.red.set()

context.addEllipse(in: frame) // <--

context.strokePath()


// swift 2:
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0)
UIColor.redColor().set()

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, frame)  // <-- 

CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The view you draw these in needs to be large enough to draw all of these circles in (so 510+ x 510+). You could set `clipsToBounds = false` to get around it, but that normally isn't a good idea.

[UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) has a simple initializer for circle paths. You can use it to draw your circles and specify a radius.

```
// Use the center of the bounds of the view so we draw circles centered in our view.
// If you use self.center, this will be in the parent view's coordinate system and your circles could be off center.
CGPoint centerOfBounds = CGPointMake((self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width) / 2, (self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height) / 2);

// The startAngle, endAngle and clockwise don't matter much here since we are drawing a full circle.
// The only requirement is the start and end angle MUST be 2*PI apart.
UIBezierPath *two05 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerOfBounds radius:205.0/2, startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:false];
UIBezierPath *two18 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerOfBounds radius:218.0/2, startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:false];
UIBezierPath *two45 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerOfBounds radius:245.0/2, startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:false];
UIBezierPath *two57 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerOfBounds radius:257.0/2, startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:false];
UIBezierPath *three10 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerOfBounds radius:310.0/2, startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:false];
UIBezierPath *five10 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerOfBounds radius:510.0/2, startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:false];

// Set the color, line widths on the path, and call stroke on each bezier path to draw the circles
[[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
two05.lineWidth = 1;
[two05 stroke];
// Reapeat for other paths...
```